# Extension of the K-Nearest neighbor algorithm to get results in different neighborhoods

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, cosine-similarity

I would like to use the kNN algorithm to find the closest neighbor to a vector. But I would like it to limit to a point per neighborhood (radius)

In this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rVUx.jpg), given the point in red, I would like to find the points in green.

Is there a simple way to this or?
I could just choose a k of 1000 and filter the neighbors after the fact to only find 3 neighbors in 3 different neighborhoods, but I would like to know if there is a simpler way.

as user20160 mentioned, my goal is to find the k nearest neighbors such that the distance between each pair is greater than some minimal value and I would like that value to be inferred from the data.

### Context

I am not using the knn algorithm for the sake of classification.
I am using a combination of an autoencoder and knn on time series data and encoding it into a vector of length 15 to perform similarity search.
I use this to find moments in the past where the slice of the time series I encoded has a similar pattern.
Currently, the neighbors returned are the slices of time series adjacent in time to the input one (which is not what I want).
Given a large enough k or if I filter out, post-search, the neighbors adjacent in time, it eventually finds neighbors that are not adjacent to the input one but then all of those neighbors are adjacent in time like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4c2x.jpg) (still is not what I want).

I want to impose a minimal distance in time, but the time is not part of the encoded data and I do not feed it to the knn. From my few observations it seems like neighbors in time are also neighbors in the encoding space, so I thought that I could abstract the concept of time and use a minimal distance in the encoding space.

I use the builtin sklearn knn, and it seems like I will eventually have to write my own version, but I would need guidance on which part of the algorithm to adapt to be able to filter the search while keeping a similar performance

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by a 'neighborhood'. Are neighborhoods pre-defined subsets of points (e.g. perhaps found by clustering)? In this case, the problem might be to find the $k$ nearest neighbors such that that no two neighbors are members of the same subset. Or, alternatively, are neighborhoods not pre-defined? In this case, the problem might be to find the $k$ nearest neighbors such that the distance between each pair is greater than some minimum value. Could you please clarify?

Comment: The neighborhoods are not predefined. So it would be: "find the k nearest neighbors such that the distance between each pair is greater than some minimal value". Is there a to implement it in a way that it auto infers that minimal distance?

Comment: It might be possible to find the distance automatically, but this would require more information about how you're using the using the solution downstream. All you've said so far is that it's not for classification. Can you edit your question to include this, as well as the information in your previous comment?

Comment: Based on the context you added, you're searching for nearest neighbors in the autoencoder embedding space. But, it seems the constraint you actually want to impose is *not* the one you asked for (a minimal distance in this same space). Rather, it sounds like you want to impose a minimal distance in *time*. And, furthermore, the neighbors must occur earlier in time than the query point. Is that right?

Comment: you are right Ultimately I want to impose a minimal distance in time, but the time is not part of the encoded data and I do not feed it to the knn.
From my few observations it seems like neighbors in time are also neighbors in the encoding space, so I thought that I could abstract the concept of time and use a minimal distance in the encoding space.
FYI I use the builtin sklearn knn, and it seems like I will eventually have to write my own version, but I would need guidance on which part of the algorithm to adapt to be able to filter the search while keeping a similar performance